# Python pool code not running

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pool

I'm writing a Windows service with multiproccesing and I'm running into problems with the method that's called in the pool.

Right now I'm able to install the service and run it, it outputs `The service started running...` to the log file but nothing else.

Looking at the process explorer (see screenshot below), I see that the processes are being created and finishing constantly, but the code within the TestMethod isn't being run, and the service isn't exiting the pool because nothing else is being written to the file.

I'm not able to stop the service since it's stuck in the pool and doesn't reach the check for the stop event.

Why is the code within the TestMethod not running at all?

[image: Process Explorer Screenshot]

Service code:

```py
import servicemanager
import win32event
import win32service
import win32serviceutil
import multiprocessing


class TestService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "TestService"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Test Service"

    def testMethod(self, testVar):

        with open('C:\\Test.log', 'a') as f:
            f.write('The method is running: ' + testVar)
            f.close()

    def __init__(self, args):

        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)

    def SvcStop(self):

        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):

        with open('C:\\Test.log', 'a') as f:
            f.write('The service started running...\n')
            f.close()

        rc = None

        p = multiprocessing.Pool(5)

        p.map(TestService.testMethod, range(1,6))

        with open('C:\\Test.log', 'a') as f:
            f.write('Finished method...\n')
            f.close()

        while rc != win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:                
            with open('C:\\Test.log', 'a') as f:
                f.write('The service is running...\n')
                f.close()
            rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, 5000)

        with open('C:\\Test.log', 'a') as f:
                f.write('StreamCapture service stopped.\n')
                f.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(TestService)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(TestService)
```

Comment: `p.map(TestService.testMethod, range(1,6))` - `TestService.testMethod` is an unbound method. There's no instance of `TestService` in this `p.map` call. What object do you expect to execute this method?

Comment: Originally the method is passed video streams and it runs ffmpeg and creates logs. I put the method inside the class since I thought it could be running into a scope problem but it's still running into the same problem, the method could very well be defined outside the class without self and it would run into the same problems it is now.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code:

- you point `map` to `TestService.testMethod`, which is an "unbound function" that lives in the Class namespace, but `testMethod` is defined like a class method. You either need to call it with `self.testMethod` or you remove the `self` from the function definition
- you try to add an int to a string, use `f.write('The method is running: {}'.format(testVar))` instead

Your stripped down program, corrected would look like this:

```
import multiprocessing

class TestService:
    def testMethod(self, testVar):
        with open('C:\\Test.log', 'a') as f:
            f.write('The method is running: {}'.format(testVar))
            f.close()

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        p = multiprocessing.Pool(5)
        p.map(self.testMethod, range(1,6))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = TestService()
    d.SvcDoRun()
```

P.S. try to post a minimal code example the next time: Strip down the code to the bare minimum which generates the error. The code fragment I posted would have been enough to explain the problem. This way it is easier to understand for readers and you get an answer faster.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by a known issue with pyinstaller and onefile executables on Windows.

Adding the following try block after my imports fixed it for me:

```
try:
    # Python 3.4+
    if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        import multiprocessing.popen_spawn_win32 as forking
    else:
        import multiprocessing.popen_fork as forking
except ImportError:
    import multiprocessing.forking as forking
```

See https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-Multiprocessing for more details